# Vba how to amend the code to auto select all the rows after filter

Tags: vba

How to amend the code to auto select all the whole rows after filter and update the Rows.select.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$41325").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Pet"
    Rows("537:537").Select
```

Comment: not clear to me your goal: you may want to add some more details

Comment: Hi, basically I am trying to create a code that would work on other worksheets. In this case after I did my filter there are 537 rows but what if my next worksheet have 600 row then this code cannot be apply to it.

Comment: see my answer and comment it

Answer (score 0):

may be you are after this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$41325")
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Pet"
    .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End With
```

or if you need to select the last filtered row, then use `Areas` property of `Range` object:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$41325")
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Pet"
    With Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        With .Areas(.Areas.Count)
            .Rows(.Rows.Count).Select
        End With
    End With
End With
```

but you hardly need to actually `select` anything and you're most likely (and lucky) setting an object to wanted range and then *act* (with relevant *methods* and *properties*) on that object

Comment: I tried, but it said compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: maybe you might want to take a look at the entire code. 
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$41325").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="pet"
    Rows("537:537").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

Comment: what do you want to do actually?

Comment: I wanted to create a filter macro that will auto-adjust to my other excel files which have different number of data lines on it. The current code above which I have, only select 41325 lines after filtered but I would like to adjust the code so that it will auto-change base on the numbers of lines I filtered. Is that possible?